# Sprite loading multiple times, not caching as I would expect

Tags: css, asset-pipeline, compass-sass, sass

I am trying to create a sprite mixin, based on the [compass sprite mixins for SCSS](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/utilities/sprites/sprite_img/).

The trouble is that the image is loading multiple times. One for each unique call of the image (so each new class name that refers to the sprite)

Here is the SCSS I am using. First we call the compass mixins:

```
$sprite-default-size:29px;
@import "compass/utilities/sprites/sprite-img";
```

Then I create my own mixin, designed to accept a column of images, with hover states to the right of each image:

```
$icons: "/assets/icons/socialMediaSprite.png";    
@mixin verticalHoverSprite($row){
        @include sprite-img("/assets/icons/socialMediaSprite.png",1,$row);
        &:hover{
            @include sprite-img($icons,2, $row);
        }
    }
```

The I use the apply the mixins to each required class:

```
 .socialMediaLink{


        @include verticalHoverSprite(1);

        &.facebook{
                @include verticalHoverSprite(2);
        }
        &.twitter{
                @include verticalHoverSprite(3);
        }

    }
```

Here is the HTML I am attaching the images to:

```
<span class="socialMediaLink"></span>
<span class="facebook socialMediaLink"></span>
<span class="twitter socialMediaLink"></span>
```

---

Screen shot from Chrome network panel, which shows the image loading three times:

[image: Screen shot from Chrome network panel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that caching is not disabled in your browser (it can be disabled from about v17).

Another idea is you include your image only once:

```
background: url(yourimage.png) no-repeat;
```

And then only change it's position with CSS without including the image again:

```
background-position: 0px 100px;
```

I guess you are trying to do this way I would just suggest not to include the image for every class, change only the position.

Answer (score 0):

RynoRn was correct, but I thought his answer needed expanding to be specific to Compass SCSS, and not just CSS.

To fix it using `compass` and `scss`, I changed the code from the question to the following:

The mixin now has no reference to the image, just changes the position:

```
@mixin verticalHoverSprite($row){
    @include sprite-position(1, $row);
    &:hover{
        @include sprite-position(2, $row);
    }
}
```

and we add the background image to the `socialMediaLink` class:

```
.socialMediaLink{

    @include sprite-background("/assets/icons/socialMediaSprite.png");

    @include verticalHoverSprite(1);

    &.facebook{
            @include verticalHoverSprite(2);
    }
    &.twitter{
            @include verticalHoverSprite(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: With what status code are those images loaded multiple times? For me in that jsfiddle example it loads the image also multiple times but first it comes with a status 200 and after that only with status 304 which is "Not modified" so it has no response data at all. With 304 it's not downloading the image again because the server says it's not modified so it don't has to be downloaded again. So if it is, it's okay that way.

Comment: you're right! I have edited that out of my answer. But why, then does it have different load times in my original question?

Comment: (I am leaving the answer, because it has fixed the primary symptom, of a flickering hover state on first load.)

Comment: I don't know what are those different load times. That is kind of strange.

Comment: Yeah! Also, isn't the expected behaviour to load a 304 once, then all other references are immediately directed to cache?

Comment: Yes, after the first download contents should come from cache but Chrome should show "from cache" in the network dialog instead of "status 304" so it's really an opened question for me aswell.